# Looking for a chip to connect to internet and display text

Tags: ethernet, display

I am looking for a small chip that will be able to connect to the internet and display black & white text. I'd like to program the chip to connect to a remote service and display text accordingly. What chips do you recommend? Do you know the prices?

I am not very experienced in hardware of any kind, I hope this is the correct place to post this question.

Thanks

Comment: Here are some soulitons from doing a quick search... [LCD Smartie](http://lcdsmartie.sourceforge.net/) [PHP Parser](http://www.brokencitylab.org/blog/parsing-rss-feeds-for-the-arduino-lcd-php-project/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am not sure if there is a single chip avaialbe to do this, but you can have a look a few examples..*

The [arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) can be be programmed very easily and all the tools, code and IDE is free and open source. This not the only available one and there are several different architectures that benefit from their own subset of features,pros and cons. Building a simple internet bassed arduino wont cost you too much. But this is not recommended if you want to go mass production though.

**Here are some projects that could interest you.**

[Arudino Based RSS Reader](http://blog.tinyenormous.com/2008/12/02/arduino-based-rss-reader-with-lcd/)

[image]

[Arduino based Gmail Reader](http://hacknmod.com/hack/gmail-and-rss-notifiers-using-the-arduino/)

[image]

[Top 40 Arduino Porjects of the Web!](http://hacknmod.com/hack/top-40-arduino-projects-of-the-web/)

[image]

- *If you need some help making this have look at my [career profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/piotrkula), I am available for freelance hire now.*

Comment: your "career profile" link gives 404.

Comment: That's because he has no career ;)

Comment: Sorry.. did not make it public..

Comment: @ppumkin Why is it "not recommended if you want to go mass production"?

Comment: You can, if you want to. but in terms of mass production price is a big factor, especially in terms of cents per thousand units. Arduino, as it is specified, is a prototyping tool. So in mass porudciotn you would match a chip with the same architecture but that costs a fraction of this. Maybe arduino is a bad example today, as the martket is getting flooded with ARM chips, and SystemOnChip alternatives that are more powerful porcessing power and better power effienciy as well as allot cheaper than arduino.

Comment: There are couple of threads running here, and elsewhere which discuss the "mass production" topic, and the answers are extremely insightful, if you are interested. However "mass" is a rather relative term, so take it with a pinch of salt. Also, as for the choice of uC, it is like asking people about their favourite baseball, ice-hockey team. Arduinos are extremely develop frindly, dumbed down devices, as as the PICAXE's. ARMs are popular but esoteric, often require commercial toolchains, and don't have community critical mass. Finally use the tool that is right for the job.

Comment: The reason Arduinos are loved, especially so by the community which is "programmer heavy" is that you plug-n-play sheilds, or simple DiY assemblies with well documented schematics, program snippets that you focus much less on putting the thing together & programming it, and more on how cleverly you put the pieces together, and what you make them do. Arduinos are your lego blocks. You probably cannot create all imaginable shapes with equal finesse using lego blocks, but for the ones you can, you can do it in 1/10 the time if you started with raw material.

Comment: @icarus74 Yea that is fine-I know what you are saying.. but when you need to create the "lego" blocks- things start to look extremely different..That is all I meant.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for an mbed - it's not the smallest but I was up and running talking to my remote server with in about an hour of the mbed arriving.

mbed.org would be the best place to start

EDIT:

You will also need to get a mag jack adapter to plug in your ethernet cable. Here is a great mbed article on connecting everything up. Bookmark this page though as it's a nightmare to try and find again.[mbed ethernet link](http://mbed.org/users/no2chem/notebook/ethernet-testing/)

Comment: You do not need an adapter. If your cable is less than a meter or so in length, you can just cut open a cable and wire the pins right to the mbed ethernet pins. Works perfectly.

Comment: Nice, didn't know that

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach by far will be to get a module from ConnectOne, Lantronix, or some other similar vendor, which will bridge WiFi or Ethernet connection and outputs to a serial port.  You can set up such a device with an IP address and TCP port, such that when a TCP connection is received from the outside world any data sent to that connection will go to that port, and data sent to the port will be returned to the TCP connection.  Alternatively, you can set the device so that when data is received on its serial port it will attempt to initiate a connection with a specified TCP address and port.  If you can assure that a computer at a known address will "always" be able to communicate with the device, the latter approach may provide somewhat more protection from outside malefactors.

Once you have converted an Internet connection to a serial port, you may use any number of microcontrollers to convert that to a black and white display (video or LCD) in whatever way you like.  If security isn't an issue, you could probably get by with any number of off-the-shelf implementations.  For real simplicity, you could just find a surplus VT100-clone or similar terminal lying in a box somewhere and use an off-the-shelf "TTL" to RS-232 converter box.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple one-chip solution that will do that without a lot of programming. You can, however, get some Arduino parts (at least a processor, Ethernet shield, and an LCD display shield) together and do that.

Yes, this is the right place to post, but the question is really vague. A full answer is pretty much a whole hardware design, and too much for an answer here. The most you can expect would be design suggestions like this.

The hard part won't be programming the display, it will be getting an Internet software stack going.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find a chip that solves the entire problem, but you likely can find a board that does, and unless you are contemplating volume production or want the board-level layout experience that is likely the way to go.

Much of your software complexity is going to be in the TCP/IP stack, and especially in whatever hoops you have to go through to fetch data from the Internet source.  Hopefully there is a simple API for that; you do not want to get into scraping web pages, both because the data layout tends to change with site "improvements" and because processing a modern web-page within the resources of a small embedded system will not be fun.  **It would be a very good idea to try to write a stand-alone command-line C program on your desktop machine which fetches the data using the basic sockets API and prints it to standard out, to get a handle on the requirement before selecting any hardware.**

The ATMGEA-based arduino boards are a popular project platform, but suffer from two limitations.  First, they are extremely constrained for RAM, having only 2K on the basic model, which makes network buffering and data processing quite challenging.  Second, they processor does not have a built-in network capability, so it becomes an additional cost.  You can either get an add-on ethernet "shield" or get a board that has ethernet in place of the USB programming interface, however in that case you need a $20 USB-TTL cable to load your program into it.  An option that definitely merits consideration is the variety of ARM-based boards on the market now as competitors to Arduino.  These tend to get you quite a bit more computer for your money, and varying degrees of source compatibility (if you habitually target .NET on the desktop there are also some that use an embedded version of that).

Going a step further, there are boards which run embedded operating systems - either Linux or various proprietary examples, given you a more traditional software development environment and library support.  Today these start at $80, but the "any day now" rasberry pi is supposed to cut that in half.  These still lack built-in display screens, though many can drive various types of monitors in addition to the possibility of interfacing to small LCDs.

Finally, it's worth mentioning that there is a designed-to-be-hacked product called Chumby which does basically what you want and includes an LCD, available in a variety of versions from both the originating company and some partners.  The original uses a wifi USB dongle which you could replace with a wired ethernet one, not sure if the later versions keep that modular or have soldered-on wifi chips.